# Почему не работает назначение стандартного значка (пиктограммы)?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

В яндекс картах вроде бы есть стандартные значки меток для банков, баров, театров и тд

Попробуем установить значок самолета для объектов objectManager `twirl#airplaneIcon`:

Пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3cpz77d/)

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.76, 37.64],
      zoom: 10
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
      // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
      clusterize: true,
      // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
      gridSize: 32
    });

  // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
  // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
  objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'twirl#airplaneIcon');
  objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/object_manager/data.json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    objectManager.add(data);
  });

}
```

```css
 html,
 body,
 #map {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Почему не работает назначение стандартного значка (пиктограммы)?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: В примере вроде все понятно

Comment: Необходимый код нужно вставлять непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: судя по всему в последней версии сделали `islands` вместо `twirl` - [presetStorage](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/option.presetStorage-docpage/)

Comment: ... и убрали стандартные значки. Можно пока пользоваться версией API 2.0

Comment: @tutankhamun вы чертовски правы, точно так же мне ответила техподдержка через 3 дня:)